# Google Places API and Radar Search Requests in iOS

Tags: objective-c, google-places-api, google-search

I would like to find all places (max 200) near current location, depend on types (supported types) and the distance radius (max 50 000 meters). I'm working with Google Places API in Objective-C language.

A Radar Search request is an HTTP URL of the following form:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/output?parameters

Example URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=5000&types=food|cafe&keyword=vegetarian&key=API_KEY

Now I need to put name these finding places to NSString array. I must make loop which return NO when names of places in array are completly. Could you help me or give me links how to working with JSON and fetch data from JSON format?